# What is the downside if we validate on when an input is loosing focus

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react form this course https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/
In section 16 working with forms and input in lecture 197 I am not able to understand what is the downside if we validate on when an input is loosing focus .

In the video lecture Max says  that "if you only validate on losing focus is that if an input was invalid so if the user did already enter something invalid and now comes back to fix it
you don't tell the user if it's now valid or not until he or she is done entering an input.That's where on keystroke validation might be better."

Why should we not prefer this approach .

Comment: The user would have to move the focus elsewhere just to see if the content is valid now.

Comment: Id say he is wrong. You can validate on losing focus, and clear the error when the input is focused, or on change.

Comment: neuhaus and Constantin ,  Please listen to lecture 202. React To Lost Focus. Here what Max wanted to say is that when the user  comes back to fix the validation error after lossing the focus , the error doesn't seem to disappear even after entering the valid input for the second time and hence  keystroke validation comes into picture .